# Javascript mocha testing "it" function never entered

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I want to Test my JavaScript Code with the mocha and chai Library. I'm working from [this tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/unit-test-javascript-mocha-chai/).

I want to test the code at work, but i am not able to use node.js (security stuff).

The problem is that the `describe` function is entered but never called.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="IST-8859-1">
        <title>Insert Title Here</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" ref="./mocha.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="mocha"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./mocha.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./chai.js"></script>

        <script>mocha.setup('bdd');</script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="./testmocha.js"></script>

        <script>mocha.run</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS

```
var assert = chai.assert;

describe('Array', function(){
    console.log("inside2");

    it("teest", function() {
        console.log("it 01");
        var arr = [];
        assert.equal(arr.length, 0);
    });

    it("teests", function(){
        var arr = [];
        assert.equal(arr.length, 1);
    });

    console.log("inside3");
})
```

The console log "it 01" will never be shown.. but the "inside 2" and the "inside 3".
the html files stays empty.

Have anyone a idea?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I edited your question to help others understand it better. In the future, be sure to type out or copy/paste your [minimally reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), instead of an image of the code. Also try to make an example on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net), or another sandbox that is relevant to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the parentheses to invoke the `.run` function. Try this instead:

```
<script>mocha.run();</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!